# Amazon RDS Aurora MySQL not using JSON index but local MySQL does

Tags: mysql, json, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

Hello StackOverflow community,

I'm experiencing an intriguing issue between a local MySQL instance (version 8.0.33) and an Amazon RDS Aurora MySQL instance (version 8.0.23). Both have identical table structures and data for the time being.

Specifically, I am unable to apply an index to a JSON column containing a JSON array of scalar values.

**Test table structure and data**

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `json_column` json DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `json_idx` ((cast(`json_column` as char(32) array)))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `test_table` (`name`, `json_column`) VALUES 
('John Doe', '["12345:1:67890:1234", "23456:2:78901:5678"]'),
('Jane Smith', '["34567:3:89012:2345", "45678:4:90123:6789"]'),
('Bob Johnson', '["56789:5:01234:3456"]'),
('Alice Brown', '["67890:6:12345:4567", "78901:7:23456:7890"]'),
('Charlie Davis', '["89012:8:34567:8901"]');
```

**Problem:**

Locally, when running a query that checks for a value within the `json_column`, the `EXPLAIN` output indicates that the index (`json_idx`) is being utilized. However, on RDS Aurora, the index isn't being used.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `test_table` WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(json_column, '\"12345:1:67890:1234\"');
```

**Local `EXPLAIN` Output:**

```
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test_table | NULL       | range | json_idx      | json_idx | 131     | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
```

**RDS Aurora `EXPLAIN` Output:**

```
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test_table | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    5 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
```

Furthermore, after the `EXPLAIN`, the `SHOW WARNINGS` reveals:

**Local:**

```
/* select#1 */ select `test`.`test_table`.`id` AS `id`,`test`.`test_table`.`name` AS `name`,`test`.`test_table`.`json_column` AS `json_column` from `test`.`test_table` where json_contains(cast(`json_column` as char(32) array),json'["12345:1:67890:1234"]')
```

**RDS:**

```
/* select#1 */ select `test`.`test_table`.`id` AS `id`,`test`.`test_table`.`name` AS `name`,`test`.`test_table`.`json_column` AS `json_column` from `test`.`test_table` where json_contains(`test`.`test_table`.`json_column`,<cache>('"12345:1:67890:1234"'))
```

The `<cache>` notation in the Aurora output caught my attention.

**Questions:**

1. Why might Aurora be bypassing the JSON index?
2. What could the `<cache>` in the SHOW WARNINGS output from Aurora indicate?
3. Are there potential optimizations or solutions to ensure the index is used on Aurora?

I would greatly appreciate any insights or guidance. Thanks!

Comment: Possibly related to fix referenced in the [8.0.24 release notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-24.html) - search for "Bug #30838807".